# How to correctly wrap multiple command calls in bash?

Tags: bash

My problem can be summed up by making this simple command works :

```
nice -n 10 "ls|xargs -I% echo \"%\""
```

Which fails :

```
nice: ls|xargs -I% echo "%": No such file or directory
```

Removing the quotes makes it works, but my point is to wrap multiple quoted commands into one to do something more complex like :

```
ftphost="192.168.1.1"
dirinputtopush="/tmp/archivedir/"
ftpoutputdir="mydir/"
nice -n 19 ls $dirinputtopush | xargs -I% "lftp $ftphost -e \"mirror -R $dirinputtopush% $ftpoutputdirrecent ;quit\"; sleep 10"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `nice -n 10 bash -c 'your; commands | or_complex pipelines'` as command. This way `bash` is the binary and the string after `-c` contains a sequence interpreted by `bash` so it can contain pipelines, loops etc. Watch out for proper quoting. You need to do it this way because `nice` expects a binary, not expressions interpreted by the shell. In contrast, shell builtins such as `time` (but not `/usr/bin/time` which is a separate binary) will accept shell expressions as the command to execute. They can because they're built into the shell. `nice` is not, so it requires a binary to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Children inherit nice value:

```
nice -n 10 bash -c 'ls | xargs -I% echo %'
```

Nice each command separately:

```
nice -n 10 ls | nice -n 10 xargs -I% echo %
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful but less detailed and post a bit after @Michal's one, so I accept it rather than your.